# report an amount in decimal places

Tags: java, database, report, decimalformat, tax

I am developing an income tax scheme, where the calculation is based on -filing status and -taxable income

[image: The tax is calculated based on the following scheme:]

All parts **must** be with exactly two digits following the decimal point.

The problem is that the output displays two zeros after the decimal places instead of the expected numbers.

For example:

Expected Value> Single Filing: $42806.**5**0

Actual Value> Single Filing: $42806.**0**0

Here is my code so far:

```
// Single Status 
        if (status == 1) {
            
            if (income > 0 && income <= 8350) {
                
                double firstTax = (int)(income * (0.10));
                double totalTax = firstTax;
                
                result = "Single Filing: $" + String.format("%.2f",totalTax) + "(Part I: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),firstTax) +  ")";
            }
            
            else if (income >= 8350 && income <= 33950) {
                
                double firstTax = (int)(8350 * (0.10));
                double secondTax = (int)( (income - 8350)  * (0.15));
                double totalTax = firstTax + secondTax;
                
                result = "Single Filing: $" + String.format("%.2f",totalTax) + "(Part I: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),firstTax) + ", Part II: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),secondTax) +  ")";
            }
            
            else if (income >= 33950) {
                double firstTax = (int)(8350 * (0.10));
                double secondTax = (int)( (33950 - 8350)  * (0.15));
                double thirdTax = (int)((income - 33950) * (0.25)); 
                
                double totalTax = firstTax + secondTax + thirdTax;
                
                result = "Single Filing: $" + String.format("%.2f",totalTax) + "(Part I: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),firstTax) + ", Part II: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),secondTax) + ", Part III: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),thirdTax) + ")";
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: General Tipp: **Never** use primitive data types like `float` or `double` to do currency calculations. Those data types have limited precision, cannot represent all decimal numbers because of that and will therefor in the long run lead to calculation errors. See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) - I would strongly recommend using a non primitive data type like `BigDecimal` if that code is ever supposed to do calculations on real money from people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting them to `int`. This will get rid of any decimals.
Remove the `(int)` and it should have the correct decimals.

Comment: ahhh yes im legally blind

Answer (score 0):

// Single Status
if (status == 1) {

```
        if (income > 0 && income <= 8350) {
            
            double firstTax = (int)(income * (0.10));
            double totalTax = firstTax;
            
            result = "Single Filing: $" + String.format("%.2f",totalTax) + "(Part I: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),firstTax) +  ")";
        }
        
        else if (income >= 8350 && income <= 33950) {
            
            double firstTax = (int)(8350 * (0.10));
            double secondTax = (int)( (income - 8350)  * (0.15));
            double totalTax = firstTax + secondTax;
            
            result = "Single Filing: $" + String.format("%.2f",totalTax) + "(Part I: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),firstTax) + ", Part II: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),secondTax) +  ")";
        }
        
        else if (income >= 33950) {
            double firstTax = (int)(8350 * (0.10));
            double secondTax = (int)( (33950 - 8350)  * (0.15));
            double thirdTax = (int)((income - 33950) * (0.25));
            
            result = "Single Filing: $" + String.format("%.2f",totalTax) + "(Part I: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),firstTax) + ", Part II: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),secondTax) + ", Part III: $" + String.format(("%.2f"),thirdTax) + ")";
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are type casting to int but you want your result to be double. Remove "(int)" from code. You can change code like that,

```
double firstTax = (int)(income * (0.10)) => double firstTax = (income * (0.10))
```